# Stripe Checkout.js and Billing address

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe checkout.js and having billing address as True.

Where/how can I see the billing address that the user is providing?

Answer (score 0):

The billing address is submitted directly to Stripe and part of the card token. This means that when you use that token `tok_XXXX` it will represent a card with all the billing details in it.

Separately, the billing address is also submitted to your server along with the token id and email address. The token id is in `stripeToken`, the email is in `stripeEmail` and the billing address is `stripeBillingName`, `stripeBillingAddressLine1` and all the fields documented explicitly [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-simple-parameters).